# AngularJS - TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: javascript, spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

I have an AngularJS controller that passes form data to a Spring controller. Spring controller returns a jsp page as it's response.This works fine when I directly calls spring controller with GET method. I'm getting `TypeError: string is not a function` in chrome console when I call the controller via `ng-click` in submit button.

form :-

```
<form name="empForm" ng-controller="insertEmpCtrl"   >
    Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" ng-model="formData.fname"/></form>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="insertEmp()" />
</form>
```

AngularJS controller :-

```
empApp.controller('insertEmpCtrl',function($scope,$http){

        $scope.insertEmp = function(){
            $scope.formData = {};
            $http.post("http://localhost:8080/IdeaOne/addemp", $scope.formData, {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            }).success($scope.message = "employee added").error(console.log("error"));
        };
    });
```

Spring controller :-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addemp",method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public String addEmployee(ModelMap model) {
    String fname = model.get("fname").toString();
    String lname = model.get("lname").toString();
    String contactno = model.get("contacton").toString();
    EmployeeManager.insertEmployee(fname,lname,contactno);


    return "hello";
}
```

eorror in console :-

```
TypeError: string is not a function
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:70:515
at m.promise.then.u (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:97:280)
at m.promise.then.u (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:97:280)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:98:417
at h.$get.h.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:108:482)
at h.$get.h.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:106:62)
at h.$get.h.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:109:287)
at f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:71:247)
at F (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:75:408)
at XMLHttpRequest.x.onreadystatechange (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js:76:457)
```

can someone show me a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here...

```
.success($scope.message = "employee added")
```

`$scope.message` is assigned "employee added" (a string), and then is passed to `success()` as a callback function. When the Ajax call completes, it is being invoked as a function, thus causing the error.

Instead, pass functions as the callbacks...

```
$http.post("http://localhost:8080/IdeaOne/addemp", $scope.formData, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    transformRequest: angular.identity
}).success(function () {
    $scope.message = "employee added";
}).error(function () {
    console.log("error");
});
```